# Performance Issues Post SSD Upgrade

Tags: memory, ssd, cpu, performance, eclipse

We have have Lenovo B40-80 laptops, recently we have upgraded them with Kingstom A400 SSD. Post upgrade Laptops works fine for 4-5 days and post that we face heavy performance issues. We are using Eclise for our development purposes, major performance issue occurs on the start of Eclipse and when Eclipse cache all the data. Also if we start the work once the Load average is settled, laptop start going in a freeze state after every 30-40 min for 15 sec and in bet the freeze instances it works with improved performance.

Observations:

1.JDK keeps occupying the CPU for Quite large time which increases the Average load to even more than 11.0.

2.Absolute 0 Waiting time

3.System is on 90+ % Ideal status

4.CPU is 350-400% occupied.

5.RAM is free

6.NO SWAP usage.

We tested the same process in Old Sony VAIO laptop and it was observed that VAIO delays start of every process like start of eclipse by 2 sec where as it frees up the CPU soon enough and gets ready to be used further and at the same time Lenovo keeps fighting for the CPU availability.

Following are the Laptop configurations.

Sony Vaio: 
I3 2nd Gen 2328M (2.2Ghz, L2/Core Cache 0.5M (1M Total), L3/Core : 1.5M (3M total)
16 GB RAM
480 GB SSD

Lenovo/HP
I3 5th Gen 5005UM (2.0Ghz, L2/Core Cache 0.25M, L3/Core : 1.5M 
16 GB RAM
480 GB SSD

Performance diff:

1. Boot: Lenovo is better by fraction of sec
2. Start of Eclipse: Lenovo is better by 2sec.
3. CPU consumption: Lenovo gives lesser load but keeps CPU occupied for much longer time then Sony. Sony frees up the CPU much earlier from JDK on Eclipse start and while caching (Linking Data)
4. NO IOPS on SSD

I will be very thankful if anyone can suggest what else can be checked or how the can be resolved.

Comment: Did you mean Kingston, or have you really brought something called 'Kingstom A400 SSD' - if so, it's like a fake/ripoff of a Kingston and as such, using terrible flash.

Comment: It is kingston A440 model of solid state drive  and it is sata3 ssd  . @himanshu please correct

Comment: Its Kingston A400 SATA Rev.3.0 SSD (6Gb/s) disk. We can find its reference from Kingston site.  Following is the link for the same.     [link](https://www.kingston.com/us/ssd/consumer/sa400s37)

Comment: following errors coming when system freezes in messages : Feb  4 20:02:06 heisenberg kernel: EXT4-fs warning (device dm-2): ext4_end_bio:302: I/O error -5 writing to inode 918382 (offset 0 size 0 starting blo
ck 3345357)
Feb  4 20:02:06 heisenberg kernel: JBD2: Detected IO errors while flushing file data on dm-2-8    and these errors coming only after upgrading from hdd to ssd